# Migration error at id in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create an api endpoint from my MongoDB database. Everything seems normal, but i keep getting the following error:

```
MigrationError at /mymodel/
id
```

I have no idea where is this coming from, since this is everything the error page says.

Here is my model:

```
class mymodel(models.Model):
    firstfield = models.FloatField()
    secondfield = models.FloatField()
    thirdfield = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def save(self, *args, using=None, **kwargs):
        super(mymodel, self).save(*args, using='mydb', **kwargs)
```

Serializers:

```
class mymodelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = mymodel
        fields = ('firstfield', 'secondfield', 'thirdfield')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return mymodel.create(**validated_data)
```

My views:

```
class mymodelList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = mymodel.objects.using('mydb').all()
    serializer_class = mymodelSerializer


class mymodelDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = mymodel.objects.using('mydb').all()
    serializer_class = mymodelSerializer
```

And my urls:

```
path('mymodel/', views.mymodelList.as_view()),
path('mymodel/<int:pk>/', views.mymodelDetail.as_view()),
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say everything is normal on your MongoDB what are you trying to refer?? the database is populated or normal as you don't see any error on that end please specify.. did you remember to add on your settings.py

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
# what abou whitelist because that's where you db will be served ip/fqdn and port 
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
  ''
)
```

Comment: Well, i say normal because this is the second api endpoint i'm trying to create. I created a first one on the same db but on a different collection and it works as it should. The problem is just with this second enpoint, maybe in the model

Comment: Your db is not populated on you model.py comment out this `def save(self, *args, using=None, **kwargs):
        super(mymodel, self).save(*args, using='mydb', **kwargs)` then save and run migration